# How to auto add value from ForeignKey to ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model

So I need auto add author to coworkers.

```
class Board(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Board."""

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="author",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False)
    coworkers = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=User,
        blank=True,
    )
```

For now I use serializer and view solution.
Is it possible do with model?

Comment: Please leave this in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible do with model?

I would really advise to keep this in the serializer, or if that is not possible, the view, since overriding the `.save()` method often is risky: it can eventually get one into infinite recursion, or in case of a [**`.bulk_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), it will skip the `.save()` method, and this not work properly.

If you really want to do this, you can add this *after* you perform the `.save()` on the super level, so:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Board(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Board."""

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='author',
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False)
    coworkers = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.coworkers.add(self.author)
```

but perhaps it is simply not necessary to add it to the co-workers: you can add a property to obtain all people that work on this with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Board(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Board."""

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='author',
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False)
    extra_workers = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
    )

    @property
    def coworkers(self):
        return get_user_model().objects.filter(
            Q(pk=self.author_id) | Q(board_set=self)
        )
```

Then you can use `my_board.coworkers` (or `my_board.coworkers.all()`) to get the `author` *and* the `extra_workers` combined. The advantage of not saving the author explicitly in the `ManyToManyField`, is that if you later change the `author` that is not something to worry about, the `coworkers` will then return the "new" `.author` as well as the `.extra_workers`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Board`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`author`</s> relation to `authored_boards`.

Comment: Property method is awesome I think I choose it. But in real life which's better: add author to coworkers with view/serializer, use `@property` or 'relation to `authored_boards`'.  Thanks you answer is realy comprehensive.